# Actionmethod erroneously called when posting to other actionmethod

Tags: .net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-routing

I call the actionmethod `UpdateDiscount` from the Ajax below:

```
function updateDiscount(e) {
        e.preventDefault();        
        var supplierOrderId = $("#supplier-order-id").val();
        var discount = $("#discount-input").val();
        console.log("supplierOrderId: " + supplierOrderId);
        console.log("discount: " + discount);
        $.ajax({
            url: '/supplierorder/updatediscount',
            type: "POST",
            data: { supplierOrderId: supplierOrderId, discount: discount },
            success: function (response) {
                alert("success");
                $("#supplier-order-table-container").html(response);
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(xhr);
                console.log(textStatus);
                console.log(errorThrown);
            }
        });
    }
```

The signature of UpdateDiscount looks like this:

```
<HttpPost()>
Public Function UpdateDiscount(supplierOrderId As Integer, discount As Decimal) As ActionResult
```

However, I get a 500 internal error:

```
The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 
'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult 
Details(Int32, System.Web.Mvc.FormCollection)' in 'xxx.yyy.SupplierOrderController'.
```

For some reason the `Details` action method is called instead. Worth mentioning is that the breakpoint I place at that method is not being hit. The breakpoint at UpdateDiscount is not hit either. I don't really understand what the problem is here. I use Ajax just like this to call action methods in other places in my project.

**Edit.** route.config (sorry for VB :P):

```
routes.MapRoute("SupplierOrderDetails", "supplierorder/{id}", New With {.controller = "SupplierOrder", .action = "Details"})
...
routes.MapRoute( _
            "Default", _
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", _
            New With {.controller = "Home", .action = "Index", .id = UrlParameter.Optional} _
        )
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure `Details` being called on the same event where `updateDiscount` is fired ?

Comment: Is the view that this script is in generated from a `Details()` GET method? How are you triggering this script?

Comment: @StephenMuecke The script is called when pushing a button. Like this: 
onclick="updateDiscount(event)"

Comment: @Shyju I have no idea why Details is being called, but I get the error message that I presented. There is no extra code that I excluded to show you.

Comment: Note that a breakpoint in the `Details()` post method would never be hit because the error is thrown before the code is executed.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yes, like you say, the view is generated from a Details() GET method. What does that mean for me?

Comment: may be your form is still being submitted to the Details action method

Comment: Is the button `type="button"`? It looks like your not cancelling the default submit (although `e.preventDefault();` should be doing that)

Comment: can you also add your routeconfig file?

Comment: @StephenMuecke No, but when I add it, I get the same error. I added preventDefault() just to prevent page reload.

Comment: @KD please see edit

Comment: Your route means your hitting the `Details()` method (and passing the text `"updatediscount"` as an `id` parameter (just comment out the first route definition and it should work fine)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I did, but now I cannot load the Details page. Any idea?

Comment: the problem is in your route. you change the pattern or you should add constraint to it so it will skip unwanted requests.

Comment: How are you 'loading' it? Why can't you use `/supplierorder/details/{id}` (i.e the default route definition)?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Nevermind, you are right. The original problem persists though, but it is obvious now that it is something in my route.config. Thanks K D as well.

Comment: try to add route contraint.. check https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/creating-a-route-constraint-vb OR you can also add HTTP Verbs route contraint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to add route with constraint and check if it works for you in this case.

Either try to add HTTP Verb route constraint.

I am not 100% sure with my VB.net skills but i hope you got an idea how to do it

```
routes.MapRoute("SupplierOrderDetails", "supplierorder/{id}", New With {.controller = "SupplierOrder", 
 action = "Details"},
 New With { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint("GET") 
)
```

OR add Regex constraint like following

```
routes.MapRoute("SupplierOrderDetails", "supplierorder/{id}", New With {.controller = "SupplierOrder", 
 action = "Details"},
 New With {.Id= "\d+"}
)
```

With the help of these contraints , it will not route the url to details action and will skip it.

If you don't want to go on this path and want to avoid writting constraints.
You should change your url pattern and change all places where you have specified this url with route.

```
routes.MapRoute("SupplierOrderDetails", "supplierorderdetails/{id}", New With {.controller = "SupplierOrder", 
 action = "Details"}
)
```

Comment: I was just gonna answer your comment. The second option did it for me. Thanks a lot